# Problem exporting video as gif in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, gif

I made a video file which loops 3 images in a scrolling animation. I have converted this videofile into a gif file using photoshop but during the process it keeps cutting about 4/5th of the gif so it never shows the final image properly.

Here is a link of said gif : https://media.giphy.com/media/3o6ZtfQ6Y8Kzbb6h7G/source.gif

All images are same width X height
The video has a 60 fps rate

-- When exporting as gif I choose the ' Save for web (old) ' option. On this image you can see the settings used during the converting process ( setting info is in Dutch):

[image]

Comment: Hi, please [edit] your post to be a more detailed question. We can figure out you're asking, "Whats the problem" but without knowing more details such as your Save As Settings and Frame Rate and whatnot we can't answer it. There's probably a good chance in doing this you'll even figure it out on your own.

Comment: My first thought is that Photoshop has a 500 frame limit. When you're exporexporting the gif, check if you have 500/500 frames and then check if the last frame is the same as in the video before exporting... Then try to reduce the framerate or explore other solutions.

Comment: @Joonas It seems that you are correct ( http://i.imgur.com/hpI88Md.png ) The video cuts off that that point, when it reaches the 500/500 frame limit. Would it be possible to export a file as gif within After Effects itself?

Comment: As far as I'm aware you can't, but I don't think I've ever dug very deep trying to find out. There are quite a few third party applications that can convert video to gif, I'd perhaps try one of them. Another thought I had  was that: if it's a gif you are making, it's probably for a website, so maybe you could animate that scrolling another way, like css or javascript, which would help you reduce the file size as well.

Comment: @Cai I created this just for simply testing it out. I was planning on compressing the file to reduce the size.

Comment: Muffin Man, the way to do this would be animating your background with a CSS transition or keyframe. You will get a file at arround 100 times smaller.

Comment: Running a test for you now that I'm pretty sure will work... but on my pretty beefy work computer its going to take just over an hour to finish. Mind you I should've scaled it down first. Anyways when it finishes if it doesn't cut out then Ill let you know how I did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really should've not used a 1920x1080 video to test this. Took 3 hours to process and the resulting gif was 45gigs. It almost crashed my computer and cost me a game of live chess I was winning:

[image]

I thought it could be done in Media Encoder but for whatever reason Media Encoder only gives Gif or PNG as sequence. But from within After Effects the Media Encoder has the option for Animated Gif as you can see grayed out in the image above. I've made some animated banners using this before but wasn't sure if it had the 500 frame limit or not... it doesn't. But I would optimize a lot so you don't end up with the ridiculous file size and processor issues I just experienced.

Comment: Thanks for the effort you put into answering my question Ryan! Im sorry I made you go through the troubles ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're always going to have issuses creating such a massive gif, but you might want to look into [GifGun](http://aescripts.com/gifgun/). It will at least save you from having to roundtrip through Photoshop. I use it for all the GIFs for my tutorials. It's excellent.